# For more exotic fruits, need you buy organic or not?

Tags: fruits, organic

Hereafter, for brevity, define 'regular' to mean NON-organic fruits. The collective noun 'exotic fruits' refers to  fruits excluded or neglected, in lists advising which to buy organic or not (eg [Environmental Working Group's List of the 'Dirty Dozen and Clean Fifteen'](http://www.ewg.org/foodnews/summary.php), [Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/wonkblog/wp/2015/03/20/five-fruits-and-vegetables-where-paying-more-for-organic-might-really-be-worth-), [goodhousekeeping.com](http://www.goodhousekeeping.com/food-recipes/healthy/news/g168/dirty-dozen-foods/?slide=11), [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/ss/slideshow-to-buy-or-not-to-buy-organic)).

Should only organic 'exotic fruits' be bought? If organic variants are not available, should I just skip the regular?

For example, my local supermarkets sell only regular dragonfruit, guava, mango, and pineapple. However, these exotic fruits originate from countries with more dubious environmental or safety standards, or  without any norms or oversight whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

You may have answered your own question ("However, these exotic fruits originate from countries with more dubious environmental or safety standards, or without any norms or oversight whatsoever") if your goal is to eliminate toxic chemicals from your diet.  The point of growing organic food is to minimize, if not eliminate, the presence of toxic chemicals (pesticides, fertilizers, etc.) in the food you consume.  The following articles may help you make the decision:

In the article, [Organic foods: Are they safer? More nutritious?](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/organic-food/art-20043880?pg=1) The Mayo Clinic explains the rationale for "going organic", but they also provide some tips that may apply when an organic option is not available, as in the case you cite.

In [Conventional vs. Organic: It's Not About Getting More, But Getting Less For Your Money. Less Pesticides, Dioxins & Co](http://suppversity.blogspot.com/2012/09/conventional-vs-organic-its-not-about.html), a well documented article exploring the subject of organic vs. conventionally grown food by by Prof. Dr. Andro, Figure 1, near the top of the article shows a definite contrast in pesticide levels in organic exotic fruits vs conventionally grown exotic fruits.